# C++ - Why do I create these widgets on the heap?

Tags: c++, qt

When creating a GUI with C++ and Qt you can create a label for example like this :

```
QLabel* label = new QLabel("Hey you!", centralWidgetParent);
```

This creates the object on the heap and will stay there until I either delete it manually or the parent gets destroyed. My question now is why do I need a pointer for that? Why not create it on the stack?

```
//Create a member variable of Class MainWindow
QLabel label;

//Set parent to show it and give a text so the user can see it
    QWidget* centralWidget = new QWidget(this); //Needed to add widgets to the window
    this->setCentralWidget( centralWidget ); 
    label.setParent(centralWidget);
    label.setText( "Haha" );
```

This works fine, I can see the label and it did not vanish.

We use pointers in C++ to let something live longer so we can use an object in various scopes. But when I create a member variable, won't it stay until the object gets destroyed?

Edit:
Maybe I didn't clarify it enough. This is the MainWindow class:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QLabel label; //First introduced here...

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
};

//Constructor
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QWidget* centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
    this->setCentralWidget( centralWidget );
    label.setParent(centralWidget);
    label.setText( "Haha" );
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If your `label` gets out of the scope, the destructor (`QLabel::~QLabel`) will be called. From the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#dtor.QObject):

> Destroys the object, deleting all its child objects.

It is not necessary to create object on the heap - you could put the object on the stack, but then you need to be responsible about lifetime of the object (the one of the most problematic issues about allocating data on the heap is the question of "who and when should delete these objects?", and in Qt it is handled by the hierarchy - whenever you delete your widget, all the child widgets will be deleted).

Why your program works - I don't know - it may just not work (`label` is destroyed at the end of the scope). Another issue is - how will you change the text  of the `label` (from some slot, for example) if you don't have a reference to it?

**Edit** I just saw that your `label` is a member of the `MainWindow`. It is perfectly fine to have a complete objects, and not the pointer to the objects as the member of your class, as it will not be destroyed before `MainWindow` is. Please note that if you create instance of your `MainWindow` like this:

```
MainWindow *w = new MainWindow();
```

`label` will be created on the heap.

Comment: Well I can call label.(some function) wherever I want. It's a member of my MainWindow class so I can use it in any slot, public or private function.

Answer (score 6):

Because that is how Qt was designed. I realize that's not a very satisfying answer, but Qt was simply designed as "widgets are created on the heap, and parents are responsible for deleting their children".

Realize that the origins of Qt are old, older than what we consider "modern C++".

Comment: Hmm... well that makes at least sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Another thing to keep in mind is that Qt uses the so called pimpl paradigm where object data is implicitly shared and managed behind the class you actually instantiate.  See here: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Dpointer

The bottom line is that if you are allocating on the stack in order to avoid using the heap, Qt is just pulling a fast one on you and using the heap anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Allocating a widget as a local variable typically is not a good idea, since usually it will go out of scope before being useful in any way; since `QObject` supports the composition pattern via its "parent-child" relationships (that are well integrated with C++ destructors), usually the simplest thing is just to exploit such a feature.

On the other hand, you *can* make it a member of your `MainWindow` class, or in general allocate it in any way such that it has a lifetime *less* than the lifetime of its parent. In facts, when such `QLabel` is destroyed, it automatically deregisters from its parent, avoiding double deallocation. But often is more comfortable just to allocate the widgets on the heap, registering them as children of the current window, since usually you don't actually need to access many widgets after you created them (e.g. labels), so it's not necessary to clutter your class with useless data members. You just do `new QLabel(this, ...)` into your window constructor and that's it.

What you should *not* do, instead, is to allocate your widgets without `new` if their lifetime gets longer than the lifetime of their parent (e.g. putting them in a global or static variable) - doing this will cause the parent to try to `delete` them on its destruction, which will cause a crash at best, silent memory corruption at worst. This *can* be fixed (by manually deregistering the widgets in your class destructor), but I can't imagine any scenario where such a thing would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Main reason - possibility of dynamic creating / removing widgets. QObject (and QWidget) desing as classes that could not have copy constructor, so you couldn't pass is in arguments (by value/reference). So using pointers in all cases makes code more simple and clear.