# Creating and accessing elements of a QVector of pointers to QObjects

Tags: c++, qt, qvector

I try adding pointers to objects to a QVector but when I access the QVector later it appears to be empty.

Here is a stripped down version of the code with the problem where the Villain class has a QVector of Minion*.

```
void Widget::mainFunction()
{
    int totalMinions = 5;
    for(int i = 0; i < totalMinions; i++)
    {
        evilOrganisation.getVillain().addMinion();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < totalMinions; i++)
    {
        qDebug() << "Minion " << i << " Has " << evilOrganisation.getVillain().getMinion(i)->getNumItems()<< " items";
    }
}
```

The ultimate goal is to get the number of items from each minion

```
#include <QObject>
#include "villain.h"

class EvilOrganisation : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit EvilOrganisation(QObject *parent = 0);

    Villain getVillain(){return villain;}

private:
    Villain villain;

};
```

__

```
#include <QVector>
#include "minion.h"

class Villain
{
public:
    Villain();

    void addMinion(){minions.append(new Minion());} 

    Minion* getMinion(int i){return minions.at(i);} 

private:
    QVector<Minion*> minions;
};
```

addMinion() successfully appends 1 Minion* but the next time the function is called minions is empty.

getMinion(int i) crashes the program because minions.at(i) doesn't exist.
Where the error message is - ASSERT failure in QVector::at: "index out of range"

```
#include <QObject>

class Minion : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Minion(QObject *parent = 0);

    int getNumItems(){return items;}

private:
    int items = 1;
};
```

So why does minions.append(new Minion()) appear to work but the minions QVector appear empty every time I try to access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement the `Villain` copy-constructor. Every time `EvilOrganisation::getVillain()` is called you will get a copy of your class member - the `Villain` object, which contains an emptyQVector` by default.

Another idea is to just return a reference to your `Villain` like in

```
Villain& getVillain() {
    return villain;
}
```

Comment: Thank you bkausbk this is just the answer I was looking for. I was sure I was doing something wrong in my Minion class but it seems obvious now I see it.

Answer (score 2):

Method getVillain returns a copy of Villain. So every time you have an empty QVector. Also you have a memory leak. You don't manage minions vector pointers.

You should create Villain on heap ([C++ - Why do I create these widgets on the heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18984925/c-why-do-i-create-these-widgets-on-the-heap)) or return object by reference.